# Angular2 svg apply on wrong element - pass xpath?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, xpath

Creating an Angular2 donut component:

**component's HTML:**

```
    <template  ngFor [ngForOf]="items" let-item let-i="index">
        <path  [attr.d]="item.d"
               (click)="segmentClick(i)"
               (mouseover)="segmentMouseOver(i)"
               [attr.fill]="item.color"                       
              /></template>
```

**component's .ts code:**

```
segmentMouseOver(i) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('path')[i].style.fill = this.items[i].highlight;
}
```

Its working pretty good when I use it only once in my main index.html. The problem is when I have more than one of those in the same page. Lets say that I have three components in a page, **onmouseover** on second or third component does the change to the first component! I suppose that this happens because of getElementsByTagName('path') which selects the path of the first component.

So, the point is how to select the specific component to apply on.. I tried with document.evaluate(blah_, blah_,blah_,blah_,blah_) by setting first blah_=xpath but evaluate() does not contain .style method..

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 <template  ngFor [ngForOf]="items" let-item let-i="index">
        <path  [attr.d]="item.d"
               (click)="segmentClick(i)"
               (mouseover)="segmentMouseOver($event,i)"
               [attr.fill]="item.color"                       
              /></template>
```

ts:

```
segmentMouseOver(event,i) {
       event.currentTarget.style.fill = this.items[i].highlight;
}
```

Comment: It did worked but with event.currentTarget.style.fill instead of event.target. I suppose that this depends on browser that I use. In any case, thank you!

Comment: How can I modify it to apply on a specific element inside the svg? Lets say that I update the code adding <h3>blah_blah_</h3> inside the <svg>. How can I apply on styling on this specific <h3>?


`document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[1].style.color = this.items[i].highlight;` will apply only for first component

Comment: see here https://plnkr.co/edit/Vxjo7MK8Vxy3mMMpTdkV angular won't let you add `h3` inside `svg` but I used `text` instead.

Comment: Another way that can be used is getting the element as ElementRef. So: `constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }` and inside the function: `this._el.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.fill = this.items[i].color;`